# What is a good approximation for the inverse of the cumulative distribution function?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, error-function

What is a formula to approximate the (left-tail) inverse of the cumulative distribution function?

I've tried the following which produced incorrect results. I can't use an exact (as it will be done in code so integrations won't be valid) method. I only need a precision of roughly 5 decimal places.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_functions:

```
erf^-1(z) = 0.5 * sqrt(M_PI) * (
z
+ pi * z^3
+ (7 * pi^2 * z^) / 6
+ (127 * pi^3 * z^7) / 90
+ (4369 * pi^4 * z^9) / 2520
+ (34807 * pi^5 * z^11) / 16200
+ (20036983 * pi^6 * z^13) / 7484400
+ (2280356863 * pi^7 * z^15) / 681080400
+ (49020204823 * pi^8 * z^17) / 11675664000
+ (65967241200001 * pi^9 * z^19) / 12504636144000
+ (15773461423793767 * pi^10 * z^21) / 2375880867360000
+ (655889589032992201 * pi^11 * z^23) / 78404068622880000
+ (94020690191035873697 * pi^12 * z^25) / 8910391798788480000
+ (655782249799531714375489 * pi^13 * z^27) / 49229914688306352000000
+ (44737200694996264619809969 * pi^14 * z^29) / 2658415393168543008000000)
```

Derived from `0.5(1+erf((x-mean)/sqrt(2* variance)) = cdf(x)`:

```
inverseCdf(x) = sqrt(2 * variance) * erf^-1(2x - 1) + mean
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? This has already been done efficiently by others.

Comment: That's what I'm asking for. I was trying to implement a method I'd seen done by others and it didn't work, so was asking for either examples where it's been done before or what's wrong with this one.

Comment: I'm saying that you should be able to use a black box routine for this without writing your own implementation at all, even in C.

Comment: It's for PHP, and there are only two very-unmaintained packages (one extension, one userland library) for this kind of stats, neither of which are ideally suited (one hasn't been touched since 2006, the other is maintained but isn't very good (doesn't handle precision at all and is not well written/easily fixable).

Comment: There is a whole section on this on the Wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Numerical_approximations_for_the_normal_CDF

The Zelen and Severo algorithm seems to be precise enough for what you're doing, with error below 10^-8. You can probably find a way to make it faster by doing some computationl tricks with the evaluation of the polynomial function of t.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has a reasonable  answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing the example on Wikipedia, and I also got an issue. Did some testing of the waters, and turns out the expression on Wikipedia is wrong. It's supposed to be $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$, not $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$. Change that and it should work.